# Is there any way around the "parse error of death"?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, xdebug, parse-error

I'm pretty sure I'm not only one who has noticed that simple parse errors on PHP, if present in very nested scenarios (eg, an object instance which references another object instance which references another object instance that has a very tiny parse error, all of them being auto loaded) can make PHP hang forever instead of reporting the parse error and halting the execution like it would normally do — I've seen this many times and in very different code bases, always with the proper error_reporting setting set.

Is there any way around it? i.e., can it be forced to display the parse error report as it should somehow?

For the record, I'm 100% sure these hangs were caused as a result of PHP not handling the parse error correctly, as I have debugged this behaviour many times; the reason I ask is because when these hangs happen one is basically left in the dark, not even being able to tell whether PHP is acting funny or there really is an malfunctioning loop in the code somewhere — this takes time to debug, time that could be saved if, you know, PHP reported the parse error like it should.

Comment: I find that `error_reporting(E_ALL);` shows all of my errors.

Comment: Can you devise a scenario with to demonstrate this succinctly in-code?

Comment: the error isn't even showing up in the server log?

Comment: Parse errors don't cause hangs. Parse errors occur before any code is executed, and when they occur cause the engine to halt.

Comment: @ChrisHenry I'm pretty sure what I've seen is real. I don't think it can be replicated without autoload though.

Comment: `php -l` is pretty good at detecting parse errors unambiguously. If you have a good IDE, you can implement auto php-linting.

Comment: @ctrahey I'd like to but I still haven't managed to track down the details on how to exactly replicate it. I just know it happens, and it probably can only happen with an autoloader, since otherwise no code would be run I suppose.

Comment: Since I started using a decent IDE (Eclipse PDT) these annoying syntax errors are pretty much pointed out to me before I finish writing my line of code. You really should look at using one.

Comment: @Mahn I'm sure it's real. However, if you're doing a great many nested auto-loads, it's likely one of them is doing something unsavory that's causing your app to hang. You could do what arxanas is suggest, and lint the code in its entirety, which will tell you unequivocally if there is a parse error.

Comment: Very surprised no one can relate to I what described. I just had another case now, treating an undefined variable as an object caused php to hang infinitely and not report the error, where a) error_reporting(E_ALL) was set, b) nothing showed up in the servers logs c) php -l did not spot the error (because this one was not technically speaking a parse error). This has to be a bug with the way php handles autoloading.

Comment: (For the record the expected error in the above case should have been something along the lines of "Trying to get property of non-object")

Comment: @Mahn That's not a parse error. That's a runtime error, and absolutely not a bug with autoloading. What's likely happening is that a class you're instantiating is returning something that's not an object. For example, the constructor of a class can decide to return false if loading data from an id that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChrisHenry correct, but PHP should report the error, not hang. Under normal circumstances PHP **would** have shown an error.

Comment: Here's an example: `$blub = 4; $blub->nonexistent = 47;` <- this normally triggers a "trying to set property of non-object" error, but something very similar caused PHP to hang instead with my code base. Sadly I cannot post code and I can't replicate it isolated...

Comment: And solved. Check out the answer I just added if you are curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was [xdebug.collect_params](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace#collect_params), which the documentation very correctly suggests to keep disabled. Certain errors were simply generating a very large amount of data in the arguments of the call stack trace which exhausted xdebug with collect_params set to 4 and made xdebug and by extension PHP to hang, even though I have a custom exception handler in place which never actually retrieves the stack trace from xdebug, but apparently xdebug collects this data anyway.

This was hard to debug because: a) it was not straightforward to replicate b) profiling with xdebug did not help c) stepping through the code with xdebug + dbgp was not helping either d) almost no trace (no pun intended) was left other than *very ocasionally* logging the errors to the php error_log file and e) with a custom exception handler it was not obvious to suspect of xdebug, since I didn't involve it in the process of handling the exception, or so I thought.

So there is no such thing as the parse error of death, and I learned to never assume it's not my fault :) Hopefully this answer will help others in the future at least.

Answer (score 2):

As partially mentioned in the comments, `error_reporting(E_ALL)` can help display all errors. You might also have to use `ini_set` and make `display_errors` have a value of `on`.

Personally, I think your question is not very clear, and you should improve formatting and make it more understandable.

**UPDATE:** Your server / computer you're running the code on seems to be very slow. No 'hanging-around' should really occur. Or could you describe it with further detail?

Also, you might be stuck in an infinite or near-infinite loop. Check closely in your code, because unless you post all your code, this is the limit to which we can help you.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems that you may have mistyped the name of an object when you are trying to call it. Otherwise, it may be that you have not declared your object correctly.

Most likely one or the other.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't help. See my last comment in the question.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not concerned about the mistake itself, I'm concerned about the fact PHP does not report the error when it should.